# What is the EU Data Processing Amendment and should I accept it in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, legal

The info provided by Google is sparse https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3379636?hl=en

I'm an EU citizen but am unsure if I should accept it. Currently it shouldn't affect my GA but I am wary of it as I have no idea what the significance of the agreement is.

Comment: What does it say? Google do not show it to those of us outside the EU.

Comment: Why accept. No benefit and potential harm. If they start to force you, then that is another thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google was forced to show this when the EU regulators got very antsy about data protection and gave them a deadline to sort out how they use customer data and declare that usage.

ZDNet have a summary of the issue [here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-coughs-up-analytics-changes-to-appease-europes-data-watchdogs/) and if you're really keen, you can read the whole ammendment [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/dpa/dataprocessingamendment_20130906.html)

Comment: What benefits do I gain if I sign it?

Comment: You allow Google to store your data for longer and therefore get a personalised experience. Up to you whether you consider this to be enough of a benefit to agree to the Ts & Cs